# yii - internal server error (500) upon upload to web host

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

yesterday, i uploaded my yii project website in servobox webhosting.

my index.php

```
    <?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../hshome/paperchoicecomph/p/yii/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

when in localhost it works fine,  but when i uploaded it,  it gives me this error "500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

can someone help me to fix this error. i searched forums and try some solutions but nothing works.

please help :(

Comment: you could check error log...!

Comment: tnx for your reply. error log  of yii (application.log) is not showing the error. and i dont know why . last error log was 6/28 but i uploaded my project just yesterday.

Comment: I think he wants you to check apache's error log

Comment: have you checked the framework path?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check apache error log to get the exact error, in CentOS you can show the error log in real-time by logging into your server via SSH and execute the following command

`tail -f /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log`

it's probably a file permission related error, by default the index file in backend and frontend has the wrong write permission for group

```
[Tue Oct 25 08:01:58.895038 2016] [:error] [pid ...] [client ...]
SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File ".../backend/web/index.php" 
is writeable by group
```

You only need to change the permission from 664 to 644 and you will be OK.

Make sure to do this in the frontend and backend index files.